# Chrome Browser Youtube error net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: macos, network, google-chrome, youtube

Im not able to open youtube.com in **Google Chrome browser v. 65.x.** While I can open all other website. I tried opening youtube in Firefox, Safari it works fine. Im using MACOSX 10.12.6.

I get following error

```
Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/log/youtube: insecure reporting URL for secure page at character position 22. The default protections will be applied.

net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

[image]

------------------ ^_-
**Even Im not able to update my Chrome.**
[image]

I have even uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome. still same issue

Comment: Hi. Sometimes a network error is just a network error. You’ve got quite a few resets of css. If you make a new user account, can you get the same exact failures in console? (This presumes you can’t refresh and resolve the .js and .css failure to load errors.)

Comment: i cleared application storage from Dev tools, still same.

Comment: the funniest thing is if I use Dev Tools to emulate mobile view, youtube works. https://i.imgur.com/4WEtx6Z.png

Comment: Are you using a custom DNS, which might re route Youtube to localhost or something ? Try checking aswell your `etc/hosts` file, it takes precedence on the DNS.

Comment: @STEEL if emulating mobile view fixes it, you might just have a bug in the server side code detect - YouTube serves up different code and behavior and they need to fix things...

Comment: @JeanRostan other browser have no issues.

Comment: @bmike but only my system chrome has issue